# viewpager2 RTL not working with manifest supportsRtl=false

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

Is there any way to force ViewPager2 RTL direction? I have set `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` to viewpager2 but because of `android:supportsRtl="false"` in manifest it is still LTR. How can i solve this?

Comment: Do you test the programmatically way?

Comment: @miladsalimi which programmatically way?

Answer (score 3):

I didn't find an official solution so I firt rotate viewpager with :

```
viewPager2.rotationY = (180).toFloat()
```

and overide onBindViewHolder() in FragmentStateAdapter like below :

```
   override fun onBindViewHolder(
        holder: FragmentViewHolder,
        position: Int,
        payloads: MutableList<Any>
    ) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads)
        holder.itemView.rotationY = 180.toFloat()
    }
```

That's work for me

Answer (score 2):

set supportsRtl=true and add

```
<item name="android:layoutDirection">ltr</item>
```

in your app theme for set LTR direction as globally (It is same that  android:supportsRtl="false") and define style like below:

```
<style name="AppTheme.RTL" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:layoutDirection">rtl</item>
</style>
```

and set this style as theme for viewpager or other view that you want be RTL . Make sure to use android:theme instead of style

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dark.RTL"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#1F1F1F"
            android:saveEnabled="false" />
```